# Grails Changing a Many-to-One from Set to List (Column needs to change)

Tags: hibernate, grails

In a Grails domain object I am trying to change a domain object

```
class Example {
    String name

    static hasMany = [objs:DomainObject]
}
```

to

```
class Example {
    String name
    List objs

    static hasMany = [objs:DomainObject]
}
```

and I get this error.

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - HibernateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /path/path
null index column for collection: com.XXXX. Stacktrace follows:
     org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for collection: com.XXXXXX
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:174)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:134)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:150)
    at com.XXXXController.Method(XXXXController.groovy:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

This happens on the production server.  I can't remove anything from the database, but I can fill in the empty column.  What do I need to do in the bootstrap that can fix or change the data in the current database?

Comment: So the index column exists on the table?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article. It describes how to put random order in the new idx column.

http://tech.coterie.com/2012/11/migrating-from-set-to-list-in-grails.html

Here is the example SQL provided in the article:

```
insert into user_product(user_products_id, product_id, products_idx)
select t.user_id, t.product_id, (@rownum:=@rownum+1) % c.loves AS idx
from (
    select user_id, product_id
    from love_link
    order by user_id
) t,
(
    select user_id, count(*) as loves
    from love_link
    group by user_id
) c,
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r
where c.user_id=t.user_id
order by t.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Lists of Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#5.2.4%20Sets,%20Lists%20and%20Maps). You need to change the way you are adding associations. Stress on the below example from the excerpts.

**Glimpse:**

```
// This won't work!
def book = new Book(title: 'The Shining')
book.save()
author.addToBooks(book)

// Do it this way instead.
def book = new Book(title: 'Misery')
author.addToBooks(book)
author.save()
```

Comment: I might be missing something but all the books and authors are already added to the database in a production system. how do I go about fixing the relationship that already exists.  I have read the example for the adding new elements.

Comment: Extending @JamesKleeh's question and quoting "I can fill in the empty columns". Which empty column you were talking about?

Comment: with the error "null index column for collection" I just assumed there was a column that hibernate is auto populating that I need to do manually in the bootstrap file to fix production data.

Answer (score 0):

This error happen when you save the instance as the next, lets suppose that we have a list of users in a chat, and we want to add a user to the chat (like a group):

```
class ChatUserService {

    def addUserToChat(User user, Chat chat) {
        ChatUser chatUser = new ChatUser()
        chatUser.user = user
        chatUser.chat = chat // set the parent in the child
        if (!chatUser.save()) {
            throw new SaveDomainException(chatUser)
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine if the you declare the list in the `hasMany` property.

In the other case, you need to add it to the parent, and save the parent to store the index as the next:

```
class ChatUserService {

    def addUserToChat(User user, Chat chat) {
        ChatUser chatUser = new ChatUser()
        chatUser.user = user
        chatUser.chat = chat
        chat.addToUsers(chatUser) // add the child to the parent
        if (!chat.save()) {
            throw new SaveDomainException(chatUser)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking MYSQL as example: say you've defined domains User and Car as one-to-many relation:

```
class User {
    String name;
    // List cars;
    static hasMany = [cars: Car]
}

Class Car {
    String regNum;
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

Before change relation to List, database table Car would be something like:

| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

| id                          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| regNum                      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

As far as I know if you would change a many-to-one relation to List, Hibernate will create a car_idx column in the table.

| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

...

| car_idx   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

If there had been some data before changing, car_idx would be set to NULL by default, which is the root cause.

So you can run a script to set default value on idx to solve this problem.